# Where is the option for facets view or face triangles?

Tags: modeling, retopology

There is the facets view in 3DsMax that allows you to see the triangles that cut every quad in two, and in Maya there is a "face triangles" option which does a similar thing but with doted lines. This is an important visual aid while doing retopo for game models.

Is there such an option in Blender?

[image]

Comment: Iam not aware of function that would make just a preview of it. But I can think of triangulate modifier. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/triangulate.html

Comment: The point is to have visual aid while doing retopo. Triangulate just turns all polys into tris. Different stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In Edit mode with everything selected first open the **Face menu** and choose the **Triangulate Faces** option.

In object mode with model selected, Open the **Objects Properties** panel > **Viewport Display** > and enable **Wireframe**.
Now you can see the face triangles in object mode.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. However I'm not looking to modify the mesh. What I'm asking for is visual aid to see the line that cuts every quad in two. This is to better see the direction of the quad and to modify it if needed. I'm not looking to triangulate all faces.